# Google Analytic’s API with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics-api

I want to get some statistics from Google Analytics with C#, i have found some examples in some webpages, but they don't work. 
What is the easiest way to read data from Analytics?
I want to use it for my Asp.NET project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Google Analytics API to show information in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306872/use-google-analytics-api-to-show-information-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Quick Google : Core Reporting API Client Libraries & Sample Code (v3)

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataLibraries

Also previous question like this :

[Retrieving data from Google Analytics API using .NET/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935661/retrieving-data-from-google-analytics-api-using-net-c)

Comment: I have tried to run the example on google but i couldn't, the other example on 2.link doesnt work. Did you try it?

Comment: I added my class and the codes at the following post, please check it.
Thanks